# Proving an inequality depending on a parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

How could I prove this inequality?

$$|x^p-y^p|\leq \begin{cases} 
|x-y|^p &\text{if $0<p<1$},\\
p|x-y|(x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}) &\text{if $1\leq p< \infty$},\\
\end{cases}$$

for $x,y\geq 0$.

I have tried using Jensen's inequality, as well as Minkowski's, but I didn't get the desired result.

I want to use this inequality in order to solve exercise 3.26 in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, which states:

Let $\mu$ is a positive maeasure, $f\in L^p(\mu)$, $g\in L^p(\mu)$.

If $0<p<1$, prove that 
$$\int ||f|^p-|g|^p|d\mu \leq \int |f-g|^pd\mu,$$

and that  $\Delta(f,g)=\int |f-g|^pd\mu$ defines a metric on $L^p(\mu)$, and that the resulting  metric space is complete.

In addition, if $1\leq p<\infty$ and $||f||_p\leq R$, prove that
 $$\int ||f|^p-|g|^p|d\mu \leq2pR^{p-1}||f-g||_p.$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the case $0<p<1$.  Suppose $x,y>0$; Otherwise the inequality is trivially true.

The inequality $$|x^p-y^p|\leq |x-y|^p \; \text{ for all } x,y>0$$
is equivalent to 
$$|(x+y)^p-y^p|\leq |x|^p\; \text{ for all } x,y>0.$$
Set $t=y/x$, then the last inequality becomes 
$$|(1+t)^p-t^p|\leq 1, \; \text{ for all } t>0,$$
which is not hard to prove by studying the function $t\mapsto (1+t)^p-t^p$.

For the second part, do the same trick to get 
$$|(1+t)^p - t^p |\leq p\left( ( 1+t)^{p-1}+t^{p-1}\right)\;\;\; (*).$$
Let's prove $(*)$. For a fixed $t>0$, define $f(x)=(x+t)^p$. Then the LHS  in $(*)$ is $$|f(1)-f(0)|=|f'(c)|$$
for some $c\in [0,1]$. Hence
$$|(1+t)^p - t^p |=|f'(c)|= p(c+t)^{p-1}\leq p(1+t)^{p-1}\leq p\left( ( 1+t)^{p-1}+t^{p-1}\right).$$
The inequality in the middle holds because $p-1\geq 0$.